# Piping Exec/System output to a char* in C

Tags: c

Is there any way for me to run a system command such as date through my C program and pipe the output to a char *date so I can use it later? I've been trying to use the "system" command but doing system("date"); immediately prints out the date output to stdout. I want to grab this data using system or exec within my program. Any suggestions would be appreciated...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `popen()`. You open a `FILE` pointer with it, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
FILE *f = popen("date", "r");
```

And then you can use `fread()` or `fscanf()` to read from `f` into your buffer of choice.

Comment: I used fgets instead of fread/fscanf and it worked magnificently. I was wondering if there are any other considerations using popen on a multithreaded application?

Comment: @the.director First hand, I have no experience with `popen()` and pthreads, but this forum thread presents reasoning (and documentation) suggesting it's okay: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/linux-programming/136406-popen-thread-safe.html

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `popen()`

It sets everything up for you and does what you want

Answer (score 1):

You need the function [`popen`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=popen) declared in `stdio.h`. Then you can read the command's output like a file.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following code snippet as a reference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *command="date";
    char line[256];

    if ((fp = popen(command, "r")) == NULL) {   
        perror("popen failed");
        return -1; 
    }   

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
        printf("%s", line);

    pclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the cast `(FILE*)` of the result of `popen` necessary? `popen` should return a `FILE*` already.